# Creating java applet or windows application that has internal database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, applet

I want to make a form or applet that will serve as GUI to a "database". The basic outline of it will be just a menu where people can put in a date and then all of the items related to that date will show up. I also want to have an insert option where people can add information for a date.
However, I was thinking if this could be possible with creating a database. I want to have this be pretty portable and give it to anyone so don't want to have to deal with connecting to database and installing DB server and all that.
Is it possible to keep all the data within the program and the filesize of the program just grows dynamically as more information is put in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several "stand alone" or "single user" database engines around.

- [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)
- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)

As I understand it, [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) and even [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) can be configured for "single user" operation, but you would need to verify this.

If you don't care about having a Java based database, you could also look at [SQLLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

Applets have very restrictive security constraints, generally meaning that they can't read or write files to a local disk.  You can run a in memory database, but once the applet/database is closed, the data is lost

Answer (score 2):

There is a very lightweight file DBMS called Derby, created by Apache. Take a look at it here: http://db.apache.org/derby/

It's free and simple to use. It is not a very powerful solution, but it does sound like something you need.